How to setup logging in HAProxy?
I would like to log each request, but it seems that with this configuration:
# Global Settings
global
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    log /dev/log local1 debug
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

# Default settings
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option logasap
    # option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client  50000ms
    timeout server  50000ms
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

# frontend and backend config omited here

and this rsyslog /etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf
# Enable HAProxy logging
$ModLoad imuxsock
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Log HAProxy messages to a specific log file
:programname, startswith, "haproxy" /var/log/haproxy.log
& stop

It is not logging every request: e.g.: this command curl http://example.org produce proper response but the logs are not in /var/log/haproxy.log nor /var/log/haproxy.log.1
Why is that?
